# Unable to instantiate class 'ModelSubClass' with null named arguments [Symbol("createdDate"), Symbol("modifiedDate"), Symbol("deletedDate")]

Tags: flutter, dart, model, jsonmodel

```
class Model {
  final List<ModelFeatures>? shipFeatures;
  final List<ModelClass>? modelClass;
  final List<ModelMedia>? shipMedias;

  const Model({
    this.modelClass;
  });
}

class ModelClass {
  final ModelSubClass subClass;

  const ModelClass({
    required this.subClass,
  });
}

class ModelSubClass {
  final String? id;
  final String? name;
  final String? type;
  final String? createdDate;
  final String? modifiedDate;
  final String? deletedDate;

  const ModelSubClass({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.type,
    this.createdDate,
    this.modifiedDate,
    this.deletedDate,
  });
}
```

and my api schemas is;

```
modelClass
[
       nullable: true
{
     technicalInformationId string($uuid) 
     subClass{
        idstring($uuid) nullable: true
        namestring nullable: true 
        typeShipTypeEnum string Enum:
        createdDate string($date-time) nullable: true
        modifiedDatestring($date-time) nullable: true
        
deletedDatestring($date-time) nullable: true
} 
value string nullable: true
createdDatestring($date-time) nullable: true
modifiedDatestring($date-time) nullable: true
deletedDatestring($date-time) nullable: true
}
]
```

and my error is " Unable to instantiate class 'ModelSubClass'
with null named arguments [Symbol("createdDate"), Symbol("modifiedDate"), Symbol("deletedDate")]"  how can i fix that, i tried a lot of things but non of worked. thanks for helping

i tried nullable value also
i tried DateTime instead of String but it couldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `final` keywords for ModelSubClass fields did the trick for me. Not sure why though, would appreciate some insights on this.